# React component inheritance

Tags: javascript, oop, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Base component

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addToCart, removeFromCart, changeQuantity } from '../../actions/CartActions';

@connect(null, { addToCart, removeFromCart, changeQuantity })
class Product extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.addToCart = this.addToCart.bind(this);
  }
  addToCart() {
    this.props.addToCart(this.props.product);
  }
  removeFromCart() {

    this.props.removeFromCart(this.props.product);
  }
  changeProductQuantity() {

    this.props.changeQuantity(this.props.product);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="product_box">
        <h3>{this.props.product.title}</h3>
        <Link to={`details/${this.props.product._id}`}>
          <img src={this.props.product.image_url} alt={this.props.product.title} />
        </Link>
        <p>{this.props.product.description}</p>
        <p className="product_price">{this.props.product.price} {this.props.product.currency}</p>
        <Link onClick={this.addToCart} className="addtocart" />
        <Link to={`details/${this.props.product._id}`} className="detail" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Product.propTypes = {
  product: PropTypes.shape({
    _id: PropTypes.string,
    title: PropTypes.string,
    description: PropTypes.string,
    image_url: PropTypes.string,
    price: PropTypes.string,
    currency: PropTypes.string,
  }),
  addToCart: PropTypes.func,
  removeFromCart: PropTypes.func,
  changeQuantity: PropTypes.func,
};

export default Product;
```

Child component

```
import React from 'react';
import Product from '../common/Product';

class InlineProduct extends Product {
  render() {
    const { product } = this.props;
    return (
      <tr>
        <td>
          <img src={product.image_url} alt={product.title} />
        </td>
        <td>{product.title}</td>
        <td className="align-center">
          <input className="quantity-input" type="text" value="1" onChange={this.changeProductQuantity} />
        </td>
        <td className="align-right">{product.price} {product.currency}</td>
        <td className="align-right">{product.price} {product.currency}</td>
        <td className="align-center">
          <a onChange={this.removeFromCart}>
            <img src="images/remove_x.gif" alt="remove" /><br />Remove
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
}

export default InlineProduct;
```

It's looks like second component can't inherit methods from first one.
I can call parent's methods from child component. Any ideas?
I think props validation is ok because it's static, but need some solution to make methods reachable form child component.

Comment: *"I can call parent's methods from child component."* That would be normal. Did you mean *"can't"*?

Comment: I'm having trouble finding the link, but I recall somewhere in the React documentation they say, basically, "In thousands of components at Facebook, we've never had a case where inheritance made sense over composition."

Comment: Found it: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

Comment: Thx, for your thoughts

Comment: React STRONGLY discourages inheritance.  Facebook has never found a need to use inheritance.  https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

Comment: So basically FB wants to throw years of accumulated CS knowledge out the window just because they haven't found a need for it.  (Yes, I know they created React.)  However, I would posit that most people aren't using React to build something like FB, and so they can't possibly say that you shouldn't use inheritance.  Look at both approaches.  Look at your requirements.  Decide on the best approach.

Comment: @RayLoveless Yea I read that too. But I'm frequently in a situation where I need a bunch of exact same methods (with signatures and everything) from some other class and every time I just have to copy all those code into the current class. And then when I need to make a change I need to go through them all and change them. This just doesn't sound normal to me. Don't know how do they manage such a big code base without any inheritance. They should have just dropped the entire class concept and keep everything accessible from everywhere. That would make things a lot simple.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to use the parent's method inside children, you need to extend parent and call `super` in the `constructor`. `super` will run the `constructor` of the parent component. So, when you define or reference your method in the parent's `constructor` it can be accessible.

```js
class A extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.parentMethod = this.parentMethod.bind(this) //referencing the method in constructor
  }
  
  parentMethod(){
    console.log('Parent Method')
  }
  
  render(){
    return false
  }
}

class B extends A{
  constructor(){
    super() //call super to run parent's constructor
  }
  
  render(){
    this.parentMethod() //calling parent method
    return false
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <A/>
    <B/>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just beware that React isn't designed to work well with this, [they recommend not doing it](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html), and several common practices with React components won't work with it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks much for the heads up!

Comment: they recommend not doing it, but the reason mentioned is more like "React has a prowerful composition model, so use it", with no explanations about what things wouldn't work with inheritance. Any examples of common practices that wouldn't work with inheritance ? @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @gaurav5430 - I haven't been deep enough into it to be able to comment. :-)

Comment: Late comment but, inheritance can lead to many coupling problems, which breaks the flexibility of an hierarchy of classes. The Strategy pattern, for example, is a composition-based solution for this. By looking for the motivation of use of strategy patterns, you will find the answer to why not use inheritance. It's not that it won't work, but it may lead to future problems and reduce the scalability of the application.

Comment: I struggle to believe that something as basic as inheritance is not recommended in react, how do you manage interfaces etc....
Seems broken by design every time I look at it

Comment: Great answer, upvoted!  But honestly, I think this one particular line is unnecessary, as it works without it in my case: `this.parentMethod = this.parentMethod.bind(this)`.